# What exactly is DOM Extension / Wrapping?

Tags: dom, mootools, javascript, prototypejs

I have 2 main questions.

1. Does extending things like `Object` count?
2. What is DOM wrapping?

http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/

After reading that article I couldn't find anything about DOM wrapping, and no specification and what exactly is and isn't DOM extension.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, `Object` is specified as part of the Javascript **language**, while the DOM is an **API** only relevant in a browser environment and is used to "access and update the content, structure and style of documents" [(W3C)](http://www.w3.org/DOM/).

However, one of the reasons provided in that article arguing against the extension of DOM objects still applies to extending native types such as `Object` - namely the chance of collisions.

---

Wrapping an object refers to creating a **new** object that references the original, but providing additional functionality through the new, wrapper object.

For example, rather than extending a DOM Element object with a cross-browser `addClass` function like this:

```
var element = document.getElementById('someId');
element.addClass = function (className) {
    ...
};
```

You can instead define a wrapper function:

```
var ElementWrapper = function (element) {
    this.element = element;
};
```

And add the function to its prototype:

```
ElementWrapper.prototype.addClass = function (className) {
    ...
};
```

And "wrap" elements like this:

```
var element = document.getElementById('someId');
var wrapped = new ElementWrapper(element);
wrapped.addClass('someClass');
```